# Не получается сделать ЧПУ

Tags: php, .htaccess

Сейчас отображается вот так

```
index.php?all-city=51
```

Я хочу, что бы стало вот так

```
index.php/city/51
```

Делаю так

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?all-city=$1[L]
```

И не работает

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

По идее должно помочь

Comment: @DivMan Если не поможет можете добавить `Options +FollowSymlinks`.

Comment: Не стал добавлять [из-за](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/90459/)

Comment: Не помогло, не работает

Comment: @DivMan Дайте в вопросе все содержимое вашего файла `.htaccess`

Comment: AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]

Options +FollowSymlinks